# PayPal Subscription Plan Creation Using REST API with 7 days Trial period

Tags: paypal, subscription

I want to define Paypal Subscription Plan Creation Using REST API with 7 days Trial period. I am using this https://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/billing/CreatePlan.html

Can anybody help me add 7 days Trial block in the payment definition? I tried using

```
$paymentDefinition->setName('Trial Definition')
    ->setType('TRIAL')
    ->setFrequency('Week')
    ->setFrequencyInterval("1")
    ->setCycles("1")
    ->setAmount(new Currency(array('value' => 0, 'currency' => 'USD')));
```

But this does not work

Answer (score 1):

> But this does not work

You would need to elaborate on what the problem is.

However, you should not be using the PayPal-PHP-SDK for anything. It is deprecated. To integrate PayPal Subscriptions, [see the documentation.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/)

Any API calls should be done directly, via HTTPS. There is no supported SDK for the Subscriptions API. Rather than via API, you can also set up a Plan in the account web interface for subscriptions...

- Sandbox, https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans
- Live, https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans

[image]

Comment: If i create plan using paypal website i.e https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans the plans created won't work with REST API Subscription agreement.

Comment: Yes they will, but only for the correct client id that corresponds to that sandbox account